Swift Mapkit - Cannot override or disable the MKAnnotationView size change animation when updating its image
When user changes zoom level by zoom in/zoom out the size of MKAnnotationView is changed, but the original animation is weird. How can I change or disable it?
The only source I found is from here but it doesn't work: MKAnnotationView.setImage on iOS 11 has an animation
I tried to override the .easeIn function of the original animation from Apple but still no effects.
public func updateDisplay(image: UIImage?) {
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(0.0)
    CATransaction.setAnimationTimingFunction(CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeIn))

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.image = image
        }, completion: nil)
    CATransaction.commit()
}

Many thanks for any helps!
